# Get the image from the title bar of JDialog

Tags: java, swing

I need to get the image from the title bar of the JDialog. Is there any way to get the image from the JDialog, there is no getIconImage() method, i tried getIconImages() but it doesnt works.

Answer (score 2):

Such window decorations are typically the provenance of the host platform's window manager. The image may be platform specific. You can use this [handy tool](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) to browse the icons available in a given look & feel.

Answer (score 2):

As a hack, you might be able to create your own image using the Robot class. The [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

UIManager has a getIcon() method you might wanna look into that...

[UIManager.getIcon()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getIcon%28java.lang.Object%29)

check this thread for some examples and valid keys for getIcon

[sun's forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5338038)

Answer (score 1):

What happened when you tried to use `getIconImages()`?  Using the following code, I was able to set the icon for a dialog, show the dialog, and then get that icon back out and do something almost-useful with it:

```
final JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
dlg.setIconImage((new ImageIcon("C:/icon.jpg")).getImage());
dlg.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("Height = " + dlg.getIconImages().get(0).getHeight(null));
System.out.println("Width = " + dlg.getIconImages().get(0).getWidth(null));
```

This correctly printed out the height and width of the icon that I had set by calling `setIconImage()`.

Or, are you trying to find out information about an icon in a dialog (or frame) when no custom icon has been set?